# Python - Converting string to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime, datetimeformatter

I've been trying to convert a timestamp that is a string to a datetime object. The problem is the timestamps formatting. I haven't been able to properly parse the timestamp using `datetime.datetime.strptime`. I could write my own little parser as its a simple problem but I was hoping to use `strptime` function, I just need help on the formatting.

#### Example

```
import datetime

formater = "%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
str_timestamp = "2021-03-13T18:27:37.60918Z"
timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_timestamp, formater)

print (timestamp)
```

#### Output

```
builtins.ValueError: time data '2021-03-13T18:27:37.60918Z' does not match format '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

I'm clearly not symbolizing the formatter properly, the `T` and `Z` parts are what I can't account for.

Comment: No, the problem is that the `%y` should be `%Y`...

Comment: Plus, the %S format doesn't recognize fractional seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 2):

- `y` should be `Y`. `y` is for 2 digits year.
- You should also take care for the milliseconds with `.%f`:

```
%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ
```

Comment: Awesome it works. I haven't parsed timestamps in a while. Thanks.

Comment: `Z` denotes UTC, that shouldn't be just ignored by using a literal Z in the strftime directive

Comment: Are you saying I should or shouldn't include the Z in the formatter

Comment: @Crispy you can replace it with `%z` - then you should get a datetime object with tzinfo set to UTC. This makes a difference because if tzinfo is not set, Python will treat datetime objects as local time (your OS setting).

Answer (score 0):

This format works:

```
formater = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"
```

output:

```
2021-03-13 18:27:37.609180
```